# While trying to register user i'm getting unexpected error?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, assets

My database have a property that I named url . And in that I wanna safe a String that user can update with picture but here's my problem . On Register when I safe the user data including the url .I don't let user to upload a picture . That process can be done inside the app. But to show a default picture I have to upload the url with a string . I wanna show a asset image but don't know what im doing wrong  . So maybe anyone can help.

here's my Image :

```
assets:
      - assets/profilepictureer.png
```

And the property in that I wanna safe the path or maybe something else that makes sense  calls "url" in databse.

here's my register method :

```
 Future signUp(String email, String fullname,String password,String url,String username) async {
    try {
      UserCredential result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);
      result.user?.sendEmailVerification();
       User user = result?.user;
      await DatbaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(email, fullname, password,url,username);
      return _userFromFirebaseUser(user);
      //user.sendEmailVerification();
      //( await DatbaseService(uid:user).updateUserData('0','new crew member','100','dfdssf')).user.uid;;
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      switch (e.code) {
        case 'invalid-email':
          {
            return 'Email is not valid';
          }
        case 'user-disabled':
          {
            return 'Account is not active';
          }
        case 'user-not-found':
          {
            return 'No user found';
          }
        case 'wrong-password':
          {
            return 'wrong password';
          }
        default:
          {
            return 'Unexpected error!';
          }
          return null;
      }
    }
  }
```

And here's how I upload the picture name to firebase  :

```
  onPressed: () async {

            if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
url=  "image1";
              String authError = await _auth.signUp(email,fullname,password,url,username);
              if (authError != null) {
                setState(() => jawoll = true);
                setState(() => error = authError);
              }else{
                setState(() => loading = true);
                setState(() => jawoll = false);
               Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>VerifyScreen()));
                setState(() => error = "Email send to $email");

              }
            }
          }),
    );
  }
```

And then I wanna use it like that in my method :

```
 String img1= "image1";
```

```
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                            child: _pickedImage != null
                                ? Image.file(
                              _pickedImage,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            )
                                : userData.url != null && userData.url != "image1"
                                ? Image.network(
                              userData.url,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            )
                                : Image.asset('assets/$img1.png'),// Your widget is here when image is no available.
                          ),

                        ),
                        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                            shape: BoxShape.circle,
                            border:new Border.all(
                                color:Colors.black,
                                width: 5
                            )
                        ),
                  ),
```

But when trying to register user im getting unexpected error And console looks like that :

```
Performing hot restart...
Syncing files to device sdk gphone x86 arm...
Restarted application in 1.939ms.
W/DynamiteModule(11321): Local module descriptor class for providerinstaller not found.
I/DynamiteModule(11321): Considering local module providerinstaller:0 and remote module providerinstaller:0
W/ProviderInstaller(11321): Failed to load providerinstaller module: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): setComposingRegion on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper(11321): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/System  (11321): Ignoring header X-Firebase-Locale because its value was null.
```

And it says ingnoring header that means no error there but why Im getting this error ????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot easily create url from asset image unless you upload him to firebase beforehand. I would suggest to handle this on app side simply by something like this

```
if(firebaseImage != null){
  //if firebase image exists, dislay it
  FirebaseImage(...)
} else {
  //if no image was uloaded yet, show asset placeholder
  AssetImage('assets/profilepictureer.png')
}
```

If your issue is image asset upload to firebase, you can follow [this tutorial](https://dev.to/rrtutors/upload-image-to-firebase-storage-flutter-android-ios-3f35)

**edit:**
you could upload placeholder image once manually and reuse the same url everytime during registration as placeholder image url

Comment: I tried exactly that -. but immgetting error that says url was called on null because it  is null so now I tried so upload the string name an then displayed in the assets image Please check my code so you can see what I mean . But what I dont understand im getting unexpected error and console looks clean . I will update my post in a few seconds please check .

Comment: first thing I see is firebase issue similar to this https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4447

Comment: Yes but on the page you send me wasn't a real solution wasn't it ?